# up date the name of multiple files with list of IDs

Tags: python, format

I would have a folder of 8000 files with names

Phy000CVIC_YEAST.raw.fasta

Phy000CVID_YEAST.raw.fasta

Another file (ID.txt) contains ids as

Phy000CVKM YAL001C

Phy000CVKL YAL002W

And I am trying to change files names with IDs in file(ID.txt) with python, what I am doing so far

f = os.listdir('/Users/admin/Desktop/folder')

for f in f:

```
if f.endswith('.clean.fasta'):

    ef=f.split('_')

    with open('ID.txt') as id:

        for i in id:

            i=i.split()

             if ef[0]==i[0]:

                 print(os.rename(f, i[1]))
```

I am getting the following error

None

None

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 8, in

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Please guide, where and what is wrong ?

(PS: only two files get renamed out of 8000plus)

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues with your splits, you cannot expect them to return an array of length 2 every time. Additionally, you are not finding the proper files in your iteration through the folder. I hope this can get you started on the right track. I reorganized the ID's into a list so you won't have to read from the ID.txt file on every iteration.

```
#First read the ID pairs into a reusable list
ids = []
with open('ID.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        id = line.strip().split(" ", 1)
        ids.append(id)

files = os.listdir('/Users/admin/Desktop/folder')
for f in files:

    if f.endswith('.clean.fasta'):

        first, second = f.split('_', 1)

        for id in ids:

            #Check if the base names match and the yeast ID is not empty
            if id[0] == first and id[1]:

                #Rename using the updated yeast ID
                print(os.rename(f, "{0}_{1}.clean.fasta".format(first, id[1])))
```

I can't guarantee that this will work for you, but with the paltry context you've provided this is the best I can do. Hope this helps.